# how can i use the telegraf-inline-menu module in my code

Tags: node.js, telegraf

Hi I have a code like this:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const TelegrafInlineMenu = require('telegraf-inline-menu');

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

const menu = new TelegrafInlineMenu('menu');
menu.setCommand('list');
menu.simpleButton('I am excited', 'a', {
    doFunc: ctx => ctx.reply('as I am')
});
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
    if(ctx.message.text == 'list') {
      // i want to run my inline menu here
  }
});
bot.startPolling();
```

Actually I want to show a text with a inline menu when the user send 'list' command.
How can I run the inline menu where the comment is?
I write `bot.use(menu.init())` but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you forgot to launch bot?

```
bot.use(menu.init());
bot.launch();
```